# Averages of Evens/Odds using Array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I've been tasked with having the user input 10 numbers and then ultimately outputting the averages of both the even and odd numbers separately.

So I'm really close to figuring this one out, but when I run the code I get the error `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`. I know what this means, but I can't figure out a way to fix it. Even when I put the `even/oddAverage` calculations within the `Averages` method it's still not correct.

Here's the code:

```
public class Averages {
    static int[] numbers = new int[10];
    static int i = 0;
    static int oddSum = 0;
    static int evenSum = 0;
    static int oddCount = 0;
    static int evenCount = 0;
    static double oddAverage = 0;
    static double evenAverage = 0;

    public static void Averages() {       
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) { 
                evenCount++; 
                evenSum = evenSum + i; 
            } else { 
                oddCount++; 
                oddSum = oddSum + i; 
            } 
        }
    } 

    public static void getEven() {
    evenAverage = evenSum / evenCount;
    System.out.println("\nThe average of the even numbers is: " + evenAverage + ".");
    }

    public static void getOdd() {
    oddAverage = oddSum / oddCount;
    System.out.println("\nThe average of the odd numbers is: " + oddAverage + ".");
    }
}
```

And the main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AveragesTester {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);      
      int i = 0;

      System.out.println("\nPlease input " + 10 + " numbers.");
      for (i = 0; i < Averages.numbers.length; i++){
          Averages.numbers[i] = input.nextInt();    
      }

      Averages.getEven();
      Averages.getOdd();
    }
}
```

Before you mark this as a duplicate, I attempted to fix the code using the one mentioned above this question to no avail.

Comment: Change your "constructor" to `public Averages()` and create an Averages object: `Averages avg = new Averages();`, for a start.

Comment: what if all numbers are even or all are odd,think carefully

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling Average constructor where you calculate the average. You are calling static method instead without calculating the average and hence you get divide by zero exception.